# Set AlarmManager from DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

I'm very stuck creating an alarm from a DatePicker and TimePicker...

This is the code of my try:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());        
long millis=cal.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent=new Intent(CalendarView.this,AvisoReceiver.class);
PendingIntent mAlarmSender=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CalendarView.this,23454546, intent,0);
AlarmManager alm=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis,mAlarmSender);
```

But when I set my alarm from TimePicker and DatePicker my receiver isn't called.

If I set my alarm 3 seconds after the receiver is called and I get my notification.

Comment: I think I solved it now.

Comment: i have resolved temporally subtracting 12 hours hehehe .. i know isn't the best solution, but i still working around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Rewrite**

So when programming at 2am I am not always at the top of my game. Here are two amendments to add to your code to get the behavior you expect (24/7):

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Use `HOUR_OF_DAY` to read 24hr time and `SECOND` to set the second to :00. The `HOUR` only reads 12hr time, this is why it worked at 2am not 7pm and why it was 43000 second off (12hr). Without setting `SECOND` the Calendar object it will carry the current minutes second over, creating an unexpected delay.

As a side note, you can also set all of the Calendar values at once:

```
cal.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
```

Whichever way, all you need to call is:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), mAlarmSender);
```

(No, more fancy math necessary like my first suggestion.) Hope this helps!

Comment: OMG thanks! , but i still being notified instantly when i set the alarm :/

Comment: i'm getting this value on log :  Difference: -43242

Comment: the current time is 22:53 and i trying to set the alarm on 22:54 or 22:55 , even if i set on 23:55 i get a instant notification

Comment: Wait, that looks like it is exactly one month in the past... Do you use the default DatePicker?

Comment: yeah, i'm not using external widgets

Comment: Hmm, I am getting the same differences. I know this worked late last night. ... What are we missing?

Comment: when i set my alarm this day at 23:17 (being 23:15) it works, but i must to select "AM" and not "PM"

Comment: i'm using a millisecond to Date converter and using "PM" adds 12 hours to the time

Comment: I was thinking that with "late last night"... Also I found that you can do `cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);` This might help.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to make dinner now. If you don't find a solution first, I'll solve this later.

Comment: Ok, no problem, thank you !! :D  i will be working around this issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11208/discussion-between-sam-and-rafuru)