# Set AlarmManager only with TimePicker in Xamarin.Android, alarm starting instantly

Tags: android, xamarin, alarmmanager, alarm, timepicker

I having trouble while trying to set an Exact Alarm with only a Time Picker. 
I set a TimePicker with an Handler like this:

**TimePicker**

```
TPBtn.Click += delegate
            {
                TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, TimeSelectedListener, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, true);
                dialog.Show();
            };

private void TimeSelectedListener(object sender, TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
        {
            hour = e.HourOfDay;
            minute = e.Minute;

            DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
            int DayOfMonth = dtNow.Day;
            int Month = dtNow.Month;
            int Year = dtNow.Year;

            Calendar cl = Calendar.Instance;
            cl.Set(Year, Month, DayOfMonth, hour, minute, 0);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.GetSystemService(AlarmService);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(OneShotAlarm));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            var source = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

            am.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cl.TimeInMillis, source);

            Toast.MakeText(this, "Set Today: " + cl.TimeInMillis, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

Unfortunately, when doing this the alarm is instantly played.
I also tried to use am.SetAlarmClock but I don't know how to use RTC time with it, can you help me please ?

I already read many thread like [I am trying to set alarm on specific time using alarm manager but alarm intiated instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932820/i-am-trying-to-set-alarm-on-specific-time-using-alarm-manager-but-alarm-intiated) and [Set AlarmManager from DatePicker and TimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569206/set-alarmmanager-from-datepicker-and-timepicker)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`am.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cl.TimeInMillis, source);`

`cl.TimeInMillis` is called on `Calendar.Instance` which has not been manipulated in any way. So that means it is set to "now", hence the alarm firing immediately.

It is not exactly clear what time you want the alarm to fire, but you will need to provide the correct `TimeInMillis` to do so.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I deleted a line during my copy/paste to the thread, my calendar is set like this : `cl.Set(Year, Month, DayOfMonth, hour, minute, 0);`
But alarm is never fire